# Upgrading Magisk to latest version: Boot image kernel_dtb was patched by old (unsupported) Magisk

Tags: rooting, miui, magisk, realme

I installed a custom ROM (MIUI Splitfire) on my phone with Magisk 23.0v.
Later I saw Magisk update, so I decided to upgrade to the latest version which is 25.0v from the app and got this error:

```
- Target image: /dev/block/sde45
- Device platform: arm64-v8a
- Installing: 25.2 (25200)
- Unpacking boot image
- Checking ramdisk status
- Magisk patched boot image detected
- Patching ramdisk
! Boot image kernel_dtb was patched by old (unsupported) Magisk
! Please try again with *unpatched* boot image
! Installation failed
```

<sup>[Screenshot of the installation log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUoTv.jpg)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is a known one.

Because your boot image was patched with an old Magisk you can't upgrade it. What you can do is completely uninstall the Magisk from the app and clean flash it again.

[The Issue](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/issues/6022)